# How to fix the java soap client payload?

Tags: java, soap, client

I'm building a java soap client to invoke a web service I previously built.

Web service is fully operational, I've run multiple tests on it with soapUI

Somehow the the client works it invokes the service but doesn't get any response.

Tested with soap UI:

...

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webService.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:analyticsProcessService>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>Alin</arg0>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg1>sk</arg1>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg2>18-19-2019</arg2>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg3>V2</arg3>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg4>SQL Analytics</arg4>
      </web:analyticsProcessService>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

## ...

Response:
...

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:analyticsProcessServiceResponse xmlns:ns2="http://webService.com/">
         <return>Succes request has been proceed</return>
      </ns2:analyticsProcessServiceResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
...
```

so it's ok from this perspective

Soap client

...

```
package com.webService;

import javax.xml.soap.*;

public class SOAPClientSAAJ {

    // SAAJ - SOAP Client Testing
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String soapEndpointUrl = "http://localhost:9898/analyticsSubmissionService?wsdl";
        String soapAction = "http://localhost:9898/analyticsSubmissionService/";
        callSoapWebService(soapEndpointUrl, soapAction);
    }

    private static void createSoapEnvelope(SOAPMessage soapMessage) throws SOAPException {
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        String myNamespace = "web";
        String myNamespaceURI = "http://webService.com/";

        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration(myNamespace, myNamespaceURI);


        // SOAP Body
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("analyticsProcessService", myNamespace);
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem0 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("arg0", myNamespace);
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("arg1", myNamespace);
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("arg2", myNamespace);
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem3 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("arg3", myNamespace);
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem4 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("arg4", myNamespace);
        soapBodyElem0.addTextNode("Alin");
        soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("sk");
        soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("testare");
        soapBodyElem3.addTextNode("test");
        soapBodyElem4.addTextNode("test iar");
    }

    private static void callSoapWebService(String soapEndpointUrl, String soapAction) {
        try {
            // Create SOAP Connection
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

            // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(soapAction), soapEndpointUrl);

            // Print the SOAP Response
            System.out.println("Response SOAP Message:");
            soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);
            System.out.println();

            soapConnection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("\nError occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server!\nMake sure you have the correct endpoint URL and SOAPAction!\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest(String soapAction) throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

        createSoapEnvelope(soapMessage);

        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", soapAction);

        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        /* Print the request message, just for debugging purposes */
        System.out.println("Request SOAP Message:");
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println("\n");

        return soapMessage;
    }
}
```

...

I get console output:

...

```
Request SOAP Message:

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webService.com/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><web:analyticsProcessService><web:arg0>Alin</web:arg0><web:arg1>sk</web:arg1><web:arg2>testare</web:arg2><web:arg3>test</web:arg3><web:arg4>test iar</web:arg4></web:analyticsProcessService></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

    Response SOAP Message:
    <?xml version="1.0" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:analyticsProcessServiceResponse xmlns:ns2="http://webService.com/"><return></return></ns2:analyticsProcessServiceResponse></S:Body></S:Envelope>
...
```

---

Somehow i think i didn't match the XSD schema of the web service in the client for example:

```
<web:arg0>Alin</web:arg0>
```

vs the soap UI one

```
<arg0>Alin</arg0>
```

I need help to fix this.

Comment: You use the namespace "web" for both, "analyticsProcessService" and  "arg0". Resulting in "web: analyticsProcessService" and "web: arg0". Try adding "arg0" without a namespace maybe? I don't know how exactly your library works.

Comment: @cen0r Hi thanks for the help i think you are right. How can make the arguments without that name space?

Comment: As i said, I don't know how your library works. But try soapBodyElem.addChildElement("arg0") instead of soapBodyElem.addChildElement("arg0",myNameSpace). If that doesn't work, look up your libraries documentation

Comment: @cen0r Good point I added like this:  // SOAP Body
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("analyticsProcessService", myNamespace);
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem0 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("arg0");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("arg1");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("arg2");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem3 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("arg3");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem4 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("arg4");

Comment: @cen0r worked perfectly, thank you very much.